# Is it possible to recover the fact that $\mathbb P(T_{a} < T_{b} ) = b/(b-a)$ using $\mathbb E[ e^{-\lambda T_{a}}\chi_{\{T_{a}< T_{b}\}}]$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

Consider two hitting times $T_{a},T_{b}$ for a Brownian motion $B$ such that $a < 0 < b$. Is it possible to recover the fact that $\mathbb P(T_{a} < T_{b} ) = b/(b-a)$ using the fact that I computed:

$$\mathbb E[ e^{-\lambda T_{a}}\chi_{\{T_{a}< T_{b}\}}]=\sinh(\sqrt{2\lambda} b)/\sinh(\sqrt{2\lambda}(b-a))\; ?$$

differentiating both sides of the above the above wrt $\lambda$ and then setting $\lambda = 0$ would leave me with something of the form:

$$ -\mathbb E [T_{a}\chi_{\{T_{a}< T_{b}\}}]=...$$

In other words I cannot isolate $\chi_{\{T_{a}< T_{b}\}}$ under the expectation to get $\mathbb P(T_{a}< T_{b})$. Any other ideas?

Comment: Just take the limit $\lambda\to0$ (without differentiating), as $$\frac{\sinh\bigl(b\sqrt{2\lambda}\bigr)}{\sinh\bigl((b-a)\sqrt{2\lambda}\bigr)}\sim\frac{b\sqrt{2\lambda}}{(b-a)\sqrt{2\lambda}}=\frac b{b-a}.$$
and the left-hand side tends to $\mathbb E[\chi_{\{T_a<T_b\}}]=\mathbb P(T_a<T_b)$ by monotone/dominated convergence.

Comment: I have never seen the fact that $\frac{\sinh(x)}{\sinh(y)} \sim \frac{x}{y}$, but it certainly helps. I wonder why this holds. Could a similar relation hold for $\frac{\cosh(x)}{\cosh(y)}$?

Comment: It is just rephrasing that $\frac{\sinh(x)}x=\frac{\sinh(x)-\sinh(0)}{x-0}\to(\sinh)'(0)=\cosh(0)=1$ as $x\to0$.